# How do I construct a treasury yield curve in QuantLib?

Tags: python, quantitative-finance, quantlib

Another question from a QuantLib newbie.  I want to price American options using a treasury yield curve and am not sure which API to call to construct a yield curve.

For example, here is treasury yield rates from treasury.gov.

```
Date      1Mo   2Mo   3Mo   6Mo   1Yr   2Yr   3Yr   5Yr   7Yr   10Yr  20Yr  30Yr
07/01/20  0.12  0.12  0.14  0.17  0.16  0.17  0.19  0.31  0.52  0.69  1.20  1.43
```

How do I turn this into a yield curve to be used for pricing American options?  Which API should I use?  By the way, I'm using python QuantLib.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Because those are yields and not zero rates, you would have to build helpers and then bootstrap the curve. An approximation would be to considerar par for the price of each bond and set the yield as the coupon.

Check out an example here: [Link](https://quantlib-python-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/termstructures.html#piecewise)

Also, you might want to post your questions on [https://quant.stackexchange.com](https://quant.stackexchange.com/) which is more focused on finance

Comment: Why they are not zero rate? What's the difference between this yield rate and zero rate? Thanks!

Comment: the treasury curves are par rates (which is the annualized coupon rate at which the price of the bond is 100).  a zero rate is the discount rate applied to price a zero-coupon bond

Comment: A working example of such a bootstrapping process is at http://gouthamanbalaraman.com/blog/quantlib-term-structure-bootstrap-yield-curve.html